# Ruby. is there a way to construct a command and send it to execution?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

The following code is giving me AWS API timeout error from time to time. 
It transfers aws volume tags to snapshot tags one by one. I think this + other api requests overload api queue. 
I wonder is there any way to construct ec2Client.create_tags command with ALL tags in it and execute it instead of looping it for each tag like below?

```
    inst.tags.each do |tag|
    puts "Tag Key : #{tag.key} , Tag Value : #{tag.value}\n"
    if tag.key.downcase != "backup"
            ec2Client.create_tags({
              dry_run: $dry_run,
               resources: [newImage.image_id],
                    tags: [{
                            key: "#{tag.key}",
                            value: "#{tag.value}",
                        },],
      })
    end
    sleep (1.0/2.0)
    end
```

Comment: Are you using aws-sdk v1 or v2 ?

Comment: fixing indentation might help

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but something like this should return an array of all the tags and pass it to the create_tags method.

```
def create_tags(tags)
  tag_list = []
  tags.each do |tag|
   puts "Tag Key : #{tag.key} , Tag Value : #{tag.value}\n"
    unless tag.key.casecmp('backup').zero?
      tag_list << { key: tag.key.to_s, value: tag.value.to_s }
    end
  end
end

ec2Client.create_tags(dry_run: $dry_run,
                      resources: [newImage.image_id],
                      tags: create_tags(inst.tags))
```